# Joining two sentences with semicolon

Tags: commas, semicolons

here is my sentence

This makes the best use of balding resistant hair, most of us have at the sides and back of our head.

The sentence after the comma does not make sense ALONE. However, grammatically speaking, it is a complete sentence. My QUESTION is whether I should regard is a subordinate clause and use a comma, or regard it as a complete sentence and use a colon to join the two sentences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words after the comma are "grammatically speaking" **not** a complete sentence. This is because *have* (in the sense of *possessing*) is a transitive verb that must have an object. An object is missing, however, in the words: *most of us have at the sides and back of our head*.

The way to correct the sentence is to add the object of *have* via a relative pronoun. The result is:

> This makes the best use of the balding resistant hair that most of us
>   have at the sides and back of our head.

Comment: Not only is  'most of us have at the sides and back of our head.' not a complete sentence, it is ungrammatical here. It _would_ work (with a comma or dash after 'have') as a sensible answer to the question 'How many people have got "balding-resistant" hair?'

Comment: Of course, it is acceptable (if rather clumsy here) to drop the _that_ from a that-clause. The definite article is needed though, and the comma has to go.

Comment: Yes, these are other ways to correct the sentence; a semi-colon does not work.

Answer (score 1):

A subordinate clause needs to be introduced by a subordinating conjunction, or a relative pronoun, and your example doesn’t have one. If I understand correctly what it is you want to say, then you need to write:

> This makes the best use of the balding-resistant hair that most of us
>   have at the sides and back of our head.

Comment: I'll take balding resistant with or without the hyphen.